Golang app running in Docker, but Docker seems to be writing to stdin to the app
I wrote an app in Go. It works well when I run it in my terminal window on my Mac. I can send it commands in the terminal because it reads from stdin. And then it prints information to stdout.
Now I'm trying to get it to work inside of Docker. Because it is a self contained Go app, it only needs a minimal Dockerfile:
FROM golang:1.22.4
WORKDIR /app
COPY go.mod ./
RUN go mod download
COPY *.go ./
RUN CGO_ENABLED=0 GOOS=linux go build -o /docker-gs-ping
CMD ["/docker-gs-ping"]

I think this should work? I stole this from the standard Docker/Go tutorial.
However, when I build this container, and then run it, the app is acting as if something is writing to stdin.
How the app should work: in a terminal window, I run go run main.go to get it running. Then hit the Enter key to get the initial prompt, and a menu of options. Then choose an option from the menu. If you chose an option that is not on the menu, or if you just keep hitting the Enter key, then you get an error message that says "Invalid option, please choose again."
When I run this app in Docker, and then I look at the logs, what I see is an endless stream of:
"Invalid option, please choose again."
"Invalid option, please choose again."
"Invalid option, please choose again."
"Invalid option, please choose again."
"Invalid option, please choose again."
"Invalid option, please choose again."
"Invalid option, please choose again."
It's what I would see if I held down my Enter key in the terminal.
But what could be writing to stdin? Does Docker to this automatically? How do I stop it?
I was not expecting Docker to write to stdin.
UPDATE:
I am starting it like this:
docker run --name narnia docker-gs-ping

And the first line in the Go app actually prints to stdout:
fmt.Println("Hit enter to see a list of options.")

I wonder if for some reason this triggers some response from the Docker environment?

How are you starting the container?  (Is there a docker run -i option?)  What does your application main loop look like; would it tolerate a read call immediately returning an error or an empty string?

Interesting questions. I'll add an update to my question above.

Try running it with the -it options to attach your terminal's stdin and TTY to the container - docker run -it --name narnia docker-gs-ping.
